# How to make i18n for jquery plugin,?

Tags: jquery, plugins, internationalization

I have done some jquery plugins (http://code.google.com/p/ax-jquery-multiuploader/) and now I want to add translation for the text of the plugins. I just wonder how to create in standard way the i18n translation for my plugins?

Comment: I bet there's some good results if you Google your question title. (Edit: yes, there are. Check it out)

Comment: An object per file with strings per language. Importing the language file before the plugin and make use of the language-object in the plugin. It's my fist thought though

Comment: @Pekka i googled, my no good relevant results found

Comment: I need an example , just how to start

Answer (score 0):

You might do it like done in momentjs https://github.com/timrwood/moment/tree/master/lang . (Classic map of strings - and grap the resources needed from there).

Default would be english. Loading additional file will set resources needed to the needed language.